# Categorical PCA (CATPCA) in SPSS (23)

Tags: spss, confidence-interval, eigenvalue

I am trying to conduct nonlinear principal component analysis using CATPCA in SPSS. I am following [a tutorial] (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22176263) by Linting & Kooij (2012) and did not find that certain steps are straightforward. For the timebeing, my questions are:

1. How do I get a screeplot within CATPCA. The authors describe it as a necessary step but I can't seem to find it within the CATPCA drop-down menu.
2. Similarly, the tutorial describes the use of bootstrap confidence interval to test the significance of the factor loadings but the Bootstrap Confidence Ellipses option under the Save menu seems disabled (or I can't seem to activate those). What am I missing?

These are the most pressing questions that I encountered thus far. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. CATPCA does not produce a scree plot.  You can create one manually by copying the eigenvalues out of the Model Summary table in the output, or (if you will need to create a lot of scree plots) you can use the SPSS Output Management System (OMS) to automate pulling the values out of the table and creating the plot.
2. In order to enable the the Bootstrap Confidence Ellipses controls on the Save subdialog, you need to check "Perform bootstrapping" on the Bootstrap subdialog.

Answer (score 0):

1. See footnote of the literature (Linting & Kooij,2012 p20). "Eigenvalues are from the bottom row of the Correlations transformed variables table." You can create scree plot from these eigenvalues.